# Azure Databricks : Geospatial queries with Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql, geospatial, databricks, azure-databricks

Currently I have the following:

- Databricks with table with devices, position and timestamp;
- Web Api that receives request in minLat, minLon, maxLat, maxLon and creates a sql query with lat between minLat and maxLat and lon between minLon and maxLon;
- Function that will receive the query generated from Web API and create a JDBC connection with cluster in databricks to execute the query;

I want to see if I can improve the "lat between minLat and maxLat and lon between minLon and maxLon" with some spatial lib. One such example I checked was GeoSpark. Issue here is that the current versions of GeoSpark (and GeoSParkSql) only works with spark v2.3 and no supported runtime in databricks works with that version anymore.

Any ideas what I can do?

Note: I can not deviate from SQL at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoSpark joined the Apache Foundation as [Apache Sedona project](https://sedona.apache.org/), and version supporting Spark 3.0 was released around 2 weeks ago, so you can use it the same way as GeoSpark.

P.S. To automate registration of functions we can create something like this, compile into jar, and then configure Spark with `--conf spark.sql.extensions=...SomeExtensions`:

```scala
class SomeExtensions extends (SparkSessionExtensions => Unit) {
  def apply(e: SparkSessionExtensions): Unit = {
    e.injectCheckRule(spark => {
      // Setup something
      _ => Unit
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm accepting your answer but maybe you can help me with something. So I was able to register things but they only work for a specific session. I would like to have the spatial functions available cluster-wise so that my queries being executed via JDBC connection can use them. Do you know a way to do this?

Comment: attach the library to a cluster (so-called cluster libraries: https://docs.databricks.com/libraries/index.html)

Comment: That is what I assumed but it did not work and I'm assuming that is because I still need to register the functions?

Comment: yeah, I forgot that you need to register functions explicitly.  Normally it should be done via spark.sql.extensions - I need to check their code

Comment: maybe there is a way to do it via an init script on the cluster?

Comment: Really not sure, because it should be executed explicitly... Init script at max can download jars

Comment: @FEST I just added a snippet of code that you can use to register Sedona's functions

Comment: @FEST you may look to https://github.com/apache/incubator-sedona/pull/513 - I've got it working (just out of curiosity) :-)

Comment: I'm out of words. Wish I had your knowledge because I thought of doing that but I'm not very good at stuff. In either way, thank you so much. The Sedona team told me they should approve your PR in 1 or 2 days.
I'm going to look at all this very carefully.
Again, Thank you Alex!!